# Biblatex turkish bibliography citation support

Tags: biblatex, polyglossia, turkish

I am using polyglossia package with Turkish language and xelatex compiler. I need to  translate english words to Turkish such as andothers, in, dates etc. How can I do that. My settings are as follows.

```
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish} 
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, autolang=turkish]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: There already exist a turkish.lbx file which defines the translations. The translations should be automatic if you defined `turkish` as the main language in polyglossia.

Answer (score 0):

`turkish` is not a valid value for the `autolang` option. You must remove the `autolang=turkish` to avoid an error.

The Turkish localisation for `biblatex` was added not too long ago. You will need at least `biblatex` v3.15 from 2020-08-16 (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/867). Older versions do not include `turkish.lbx`.

The following document compiles fine for me on a current TeX system with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage{turkish} 
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Lorem}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson ve Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”. İçinde: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), ss. 377–395. doı: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]